# Extended control events

Tags: c#, winforms, events

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a custom `Chart` control, and to execute a certain function whenever the data in the `DataSource` changes.

Custom chart code:

```
public partial class MyChart : Chart
{
    public StockChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataBindings.CollectionChanged += new CollectionChangeEventHandler(OnDataChange);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    private void OnDataChange(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Changed");
    }
}
```

Code running on the UI thread:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    BindingList<MyObject> Data;

    public MyForm()
    { 
        InitComponent();

        Data = new BindingList<MyObject>();

        mychart.DataSource = Data;
    }

    public void AddData(MyObject object)
    {
        Data.Add(object);
        //Here the OnDataChange should be triggered, but nothing happens!
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataBindings aren't changing.  Your DataSource is adding a new item.  That's different.

You could use the OnBindingContextChanged method:

```
public class MyChart : Chart {

  protected override void OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e) {
    ((BindingList<MyObject>)this.DataSource).ListChanged -= MyChart_ListChanged;
    ((BindingList<MyObject>)this.DataSource).ListChanged += MyChart_ListChanged;
    base.OnBindingContextChanged(e);
  }

  void MyChart_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
    // something happened in the list...
  }
}
```

But that makes your control dependent on knowing the DataSource is a `BindingList<MyObject>` collection.  Probably not a good design.  Consider just using the ListChanged event in your form that has the BindingList declared instead.

Comment: Perfect! But just to know, why without the initial "subtraction" I get the event triggered twice?

Comment: OnBindingContextChanged is probably getting called multiple times when the control is initialized, so that would keep adding event listeners.  You only want one, so the simple hack is to just remove it before adding it.